# Remove Images from Image Collection in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, loop, time-series

In the below code, I'm going to remove some images from image collection by if condition in .map() instead of filter.neq(), what should I do for this purpose?

```
Map.centerObject(table);
Map.addLayer(table);

var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
.filterBounds(table)
.filterDate('2016-01-01','2020-01-01')
.filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',45))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index','20170910T071621_20170910T073037_T39SUR').not())
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index','20180518T071621_20180518T071934_T39SUR').not());


print(s2);
```

code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/7dc1cf120153095b7f48c133015398ca

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In almost all cases, you are better off using filters. My understanding is that it's significantly more efficient. But if you really need to, you can filter out an element in `map()` by returning `null` and setting the `dropNulls` argument to `true`.

```
ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
  .filterBounds(table)
  .filterDate('2016-01-01','2020-01-01')
  .map(function (image) {
    var index = image.getString('system:index')
    var include = image.getNumber('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE').lt(45)
      .and(index.match('20170910T071621_20170910T073037_T39SUR').size().eq(0))
      .and(index.match('20180518T071621_20180518T071934_T39SUR').size().eq(0))
    return ee.Algorithms.If(include, image, null)
  }, true)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/20db63310dc07ee66257e0c7de932e0c